# adb start server failed

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Hi，i find problem when used android studio ,open my android project ,adb always start-server fail.

about android studio:

> Android Studio 4.1 Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on
> September 23, 2020 Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593
> x86_64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o macOS 10.15.5
> GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep Memory: 1979M Cores: 12 Registry:
> ide.windowSystem.autoShowProcessPopup=true,
> ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, search.everywhere.actions=false

platform-tools

**30.0.4**

this android studio event adb log:

> 15:50 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 15:50 '/Users/zhengzhong23/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
> start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
>
> 15:50 Gradle sync started
>
> 15:50 Adb connection Error:EOF
>
> 15:50 Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException:
> Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused,
> IPv6 attempt: Connection refused
>
> 15:50 Failed to start monitoring 0209ba99
>
> 15:50 Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
>
> 15:50 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 15:50 '/Users/zhengzhong23/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
> start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
>
> 15:50 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 15:50 '/Users/zhengzhong23/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
> start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
>
> 15:51 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 15:51 '/Users/zhengzhong23/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
> start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
>
> 15:51 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 15:51 '/Users/zhengzhong23/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
> start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
>
> 15:51 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 15:51 '/Users/zhengzhong23/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
> start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
>
> 15:51 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 15:51 '/Users/zhengzhong23/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
> start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
>
> 15:51 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 15:51 '/Users/zhengzhong23/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
> start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
>
> 15:51 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 15:51 '/Users/zhengzhong23/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
> start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
>
> 15:51 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 15:51 '/Users/zhengzhong23/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
> start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
>
> 15:51 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

please,help me

Comment: I have the same problem. How have you resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your drive C and in android studio delete the ADB file and then run it.

Comment: Can You specify please, what ADB file must be deleted and where exactly?